# How to achieve partial output to cmd window and partial redirection to file for c++ program?

Tags: c++

I know how to use pipe operator to redirect whole output of a c++ executable file(generated by my c++ code),but the question is that there are some contents that do not need to redirect to file, but to cmd window.
In my limited experience with c++ programming, I guess there may be some kind of redirection method with higher priority than redirection pipe operator, but I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::cout` for things that you want to redirect to the file, and `std::cerr` for things that you want to print to the command window. Normal redirection with `>` and `|` only affects the former.

Comment: Ok, I just did not click accept because the site requires an answer can't be accepted within 4 minutes, your answer is so timely！